# Socket Timeout Exception In Okhttp3Client

Tags: java, okhttp

In work, I encounter a problem like this. I used Rest-Template embedded in Spring. HttpClient used is OkHttp3Client. In On-line running, the error like below happens once an hour.It seems like socket is closed,but OkHttp3Client uses long connection to make many requests share the same connection. Who could tell my why?

```
 @Bean("restTemplate")
 public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
   OkHttp3ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new 
   OkHttp3ClientHttpRequestFactory();
   clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
   clientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
   RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
   restTemplate.setRequestFactory(clientHttpRequestFactory);
   return restTemplate;
 }
```

The error info:

```
 org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST 
  request for "http://*****": timeout; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout 
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:666) 
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613) 
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:380)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) 
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) 
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) 
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85) 
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor114.invoke(Unknown Source) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629) 
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618) 
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70) 
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) 
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) 
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) 
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) 
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) 
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) 
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) 
at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52) 
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168) 
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85) 
at com.ppdai.passport.interceptor.StatisticsAndLogInterceptor.around(StatisticsAndLogInterceptor.java:112) 
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor75.invoke(Unknown Source) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629) 
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618) 
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70) 
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168) 
at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:52) 
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168) 
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) 
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) 
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) 
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor102.invoke(Unknown Source) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) 
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) 
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) 
at com.ppdai.user.infrastructure.filter.AbstractAuthFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthFilter.java:115) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) 
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) 
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) 
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) 
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) 
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) 
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout 
at okio.Okio$4.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:227) 
at okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:284) 
at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:240) 
at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:325) 
at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:314) 
at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:210) 
at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189) 
at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:67) 
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) 
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45) 
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) 
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) 
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93) 
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) 
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) 
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93) 
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) 
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120) 
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) 
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) 
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:179) 
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:63) 
at org.springframework.http.client.OkHttp3ClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(OkHttp3ClientHttpRequest.java:68) 
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) 
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) 
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:652) 
 ... 99 common frames omitted 
 Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed 
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:203) 
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) 
   at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:138) 
   at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:236) 
    ... 122 common frames omitted
```

Comment: are you able to connect to server/ ping to server?